# Java swing freeze while performing task

Tags: java, swing, integer

I have this little piece of code that is supposed to take the remainder value and assign to another object.

```
private void showOnesSecsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    int secs = Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText()); //Grabs the value of the oneSecs JTextfield
    String lctn = "images\\" + secs + ".png"; //Looks for the image that corresponds with the number and has an extension of .png
    oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon (lctn));//Uses the lctn to assign the corresponding image to the oneSecsDisplay button

    while (secs > 9){
        secSecsDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon ("images\\" + secs/10 + ".png"));
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, I know that the **oneSecsDisplay** will only show a digit value from 0 - 9 (that works fine)

However when it gets to 10; it is supposed to prompt the next display, **secSecsDisplay** to display the tens value. i.e 14 -> **secSecsDisplay shows 1** and **oneSecsDisplay shows 4**

Comment: Use a swing Timer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: It has to be manual to start off with, so that if you enter a value like 59, each digit shows in their corresponding display

Comment: You loop is an infinite loop if secs > 9 and never entered if it isn't...

Comment: So then how would I redo the loop so that it doesn't get stuck trying to update the next value? Thank you for pointing that out to me @Durandal

Comment: Errm isn't that obvious, because it *really* should be. Replace *while* with *if*.

Comment: No sorry, that wasn't obvious to me, but thank you. Okay now I can't get the digit value to stay in the correct display, as soon as a number bigger than 9 is entered, the digit value goes away

Comment: Swing is single threaded, don't block the event dispatching thread otherwise you will prevent it from updating the uii. See ControlAltDel's comment for a fix